# How to maintain a circular arc with a large arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, arc

I want a circular arc with a big arrowhead, but when I do so, it messes up the arc's concentricity:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  bigframearrow/.style={-{Latex[length=12mm,width=8mm]}, line width=3mm},
]
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,0}

\def\R{5cm}
\fill[gray] (0,0) circle (\R);
\draw[bigframearrow, myorange] (60:\R+0.2cm) arc (60:120:\R+0.2cm);
\draw[black] (60:\R+0.2cm) arc (60:120:\R+0.2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way I can fix?

Comment: The problem here is not with the arrow, but with the shortening. I faced it several times and couldn't find a simple solution. Try and add `shorten >=1cm` to your arc without the arrow tip (and the line width=3mm), and you will face exactly the same issue. A solution could be to draw the arc, draw a white end then draw the arrow tip... I wish someone would come with a magic wand!

Answer (score 12):

You can avoid this by adding the `bending` library.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  bigframearrow/.style={-{Latex[length=12mm,width=8mm]}, line width=3mm},
]
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,0}

\def\R{5cm}
\fill[gray] (0,0) circle (\R);
\draw[bigframearrow, myorange] (60:\R+0.2cm) arc (60:120:\R+0.2cm);
\draw[black] (60:\R+0.2cm) arc (60:120:\R+0.2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]